# How to substitute array name with variable in korn shell?

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have two arrays: options and args, and I want to display the contents of arrays.
For that I wish to write a general function which will take the name of array and display its contents.

eg.

```
set -A options val1 val2 val3
set -A args var1 var2 var3
```

What I am doing now to display the contents:

```
dispArr() {
    i=0
    while [ "$i" -lt "${#options[*]}" ] #line1
    do
        echo ${options[$i]} #line2
        ((i=i+1))
    done
}
```

currently I have two different functions, one for array "options" and other for array "args"

I want to substitute array names ("options" in above code) in line1 and line2 with variables, so that I can make a call like following to print the contents of any array :

```
dispArr options #print the contents of array "options"
dispArr args #print the contents of array "args"
```

I tried providing $1 in place of array names but it didn't work.
I also tried different quotes but it didn't work too.

I am new to unix and shell scripting, so any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of ksh? ksh88 or ksh93? Do `ksh --version` -- empty output, then it's ksh88

Comment: @glennjackman Following is the output of ksh --version:
version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u 2011-02-08

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ksh93

```
dispArr() { nameref arr=$1; printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"; }
```

ksh88

```
dispArr() { eval printf "%s\\\\n" "\${${1}[@]}"; }
```